# Examples of Measures that are Equivalent to their Self-Convolution

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-transform, convolution

I'm interested in seeing (or generating) lots of examples of measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu \sim \mu * \mu$.  I'd love a reference (or even just a name) for these measures or, alternatively, a way to make up examples.  I'd like to at least know that there are many measure classes whose representatives satisfy $\mu \sim \mu * \mu$, if we can't explicitly generate a family of examples.

At first, I thought it might be easier to think about these measures through the Fourier transform $\hat{\mu}$, since the Fourier transform of $\mu * \mu$ is just the product of $\hat{\mu}$ with itself, but I don't know how to determine equivalence of the measures $\mu$ and $\mu * \mu$ in terms of their Fourier transforms.

In my actual application, I also want the Fourier transform to decay at infinity, i.e. $\lim_{|t|\rightarrow \infty} \hat{\mu}(t) = 0$, so I would also appreciate comments/references about generating those examples in particular, but I'm interested in any examples where $\mu \sim \mu * \mu$, whether they meet my decay condition or not.  If it's not easy to generate examples, I'd still like to see whether there's a "large" set of measure classes with these properties.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your example.  Isn't your $\mu$ equivalent to Lebesgue measure?  That's a valid example, for sure, but I'm guessing that I'm missing something.

Comment: No, the Lebesgue measure would be just $\mathrm{d}x$ :o

Comment: For equality there is $d\mu=f(x)dx,f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n \frac{e^{2i\pi a_n x}-e^{2i\pi b_n x}}{2i\pi x}$ but it is not fully a measure (not integrable). For equivalence any $f > 0\in L^1\cap c_0$. You are asking for more classes ?

Comment: @reuns My mistake - I'll edit the question to reflect that.  Yes, I did intend to ask for more measure classes.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent measures?

Comment: @Jose27 Two measures are equivalent if they have the same null sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)  By "measure classes", I mean the equivalence classes of measures up to this notion of equivalence.